# wsimport - schema descriptor not defined

Tags: java, xml, web-services, command-line, wsdl

i am using wsimport to import the wsdl File from a server. Here is the command I am using:

```
X:>wsimport -keep -verbose http://xxxxxxxxxx

parsing WSDL...


[ERROR] Schema descriptor {http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX in message part "in" is not defined and could not be bound to Java. Perhaps the schema descriptor is not defined in the schema imported/included in the WSDL. You can either a
dd such imports/includes or run wsimport and provide the schema location using -
b switch.
```

How can I import the wsdl Files?

Comment: The message is telling you that wsimport cannot access the type definition for the element related to the 'in' message part...presumably the request.  Although you could not (unless a very lenient web service) construct the request without the type definition, you could mock a request definition just to get the method stubs processed.  If you provided the actual fully-qualified name which is missing (according to the error), a responder could provide the required schema type to act as a mock request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specified the exact JDK version

> %AS_HOME%/bin/wsimport  -keep -d  ./build     -p  com.sample.hello   http://localhost:8080/HelloSvr/HelloService?wsdl

Comment: could you explain ?